# What are good examples of how software helps solving today's environmental problems?

Tags: environmental-protection, pollution, software, emissions, deforestation

I'm collecting examples and inspiration of how existing software products or applications of any kind - non-profit or commercial - *directly* help solving or preventing environmental problems like GHG emissions, deforestation, environmental degradation, pollution, resource depletion and others.
Of course the *directly* part is very debatable, so here are some good examples of direct and clear impact I have until now:

- AI that detects sounds of chainsaw and monitors on-site deforestation (Rainforest Connection (RFCx))
- web platform that allows people to find food/meals in their city to buy that would be otherwise get thrown away (by restaurants, hotels, supermarkets - Too Good To Go
- optimising software libraries to be significantly smaller in size and thus make servers delivering them to have smaller carbon footprint (one unspecified Wordpress plugin)

Comment: And then there're the false positives ;) https://youtu.be/mSB71jNq-yQ?t=145

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival I don't understand how is your comment useful or constructive to my question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is overly broad.

Comment: @DavidHammen How can it get more concrete, can you suggest improvements?